# Migrating from Entity Framework to Entity Framework Core: OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm still trying to migrate my wpf application from entity framework to entity framework core I am using the code first but I'm getting some issues; I need your help, please:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Script>().Property(x => x.Code).IsMaxLength();
    modelBuilder.Entity<CalculationSelector>().HasMany(x => x.CalculationTypes).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<WarehouseConsumption>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<PeriodicConsumption>().HasMany(p => p.WarehouseConsumptions).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(x => x.PeriodicConsumptionId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CalculationType>().Property(x => x.Amount).HasPrecision(precision, scale);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Numerator>().Property(x => x.LastUpdateTime).IsConcurrencyToken().HasColumnType("timestamp");
}
```

First of all, I'm getting an error in the IsMaxLength() function; In this case I can use MaxLength() and the value must be between the parentheses?

> CS1061 'PropertyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'IsMaxLength' and no accessible extension method 'IsMaxLength' accepting a first argument of type 'PropertyBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Then I get an error in the HasMany()-WithMany() combination; There is no support for many-to-many relationships in the Entity Framework Core?

> 'CollectionNavigationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'WithMany' and no accessible extension method 'WithMany' accepting a first argument of type 'CollectionNavigationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I also have errors in the functions HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(), WithRequired(), HasPrecision(), HasColumnType().

Help please, what can I do in each case, I am a newbie

Comment: Hi, it would help if you show the errors

Comment: Thanks @Stefan I have edited the publication with the changes, any help would be greatly appreciated